# Calculating mean of each column in matrix with input value

Tags: r

Please see my code below

I want to calculate mean of each column individually based on input value of column and given mattrix.

e,g. m_col(m1, 2) . m1 is a given mattrix and 2 in column no. of given mattrix. Please help.

Comment: what is the issue of using `colMeans`?

Comment: Hi.. Actually colMeans will calculate mean for all column is single shot. i want to calculate separately for all columns in a given matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this:

```
#Data
mat <- matrix(1:3,5,6)
#Function
m_col <- function(m, col)
{
  mean(m[,col])
}
#Apply
m_col(mat, 2)
```

Comment: @AmitPeer Always a pleasure helping!